# How PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties mapped to Configuration POJO using Spring at Runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, spring-cloud-config

I have a service which is which consumes many external services. I am creating properties file for each of them, these are quite few predefined properties such as **twil.props, tweet.props, hubpot.props etc**

So as to get those properites at runtime I am using **PropertiesLoaderUtils** like below:

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/"+apiname +".properties");
Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

I would like to get these properties into POJO just like ConfigurationProperties, I have designed following POJO for that purpose:

```
public class APIConfig {

    private Integer paginationPerPage;

    private String paginationKeyword;

    private String paginationStyle;

    private String countParamKeyword;

    private String countKey;

    private String offsetKey;
}
```

I will maintain properties file in such a way so that these can be easily mapped to Config POJO:

Properties for twil.properties

```
api.paginationPerPage=10
api.paginationKeyword=limit
api.paginationStyle=offset
api.countParamKeyword=count
api.countKey=count
api.offsetKey=offset
```

So can I get this directly into given POJO by utilizing any of Spring Boot / Spring utility, config etc?

Comment: You use SpringBoot and you want "ConfigurationProperties" function, why don't you like a factory method approach with a Configuration class and two methods with "Bean"+"ConfigurationProperties"? In one you could use the file A, and in the other the file B

Comment: @sigur - I dont want to go on adding different factory implementation. Later on I can keep these all config files in independent config server. and read it without restarting server. I am thinking of zero downtime solution

Answer (score 0):

As it is noticed at comments, the only right solution here which includes zero downtime, namely `@RefreshScope`.

1. Use spring cloud config dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. Add to your code

```java
@Configuration
class SomeConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties("twil.props")
    APIConfig twilConfig() {
        return new ApiConfig()
    }

    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    @ConfigurationProperties("tweet.props")
    APIConfig tweetConfig() {
        return new ApiConfig()
    }

}
```

Usage: `@Autowire APIConfig tweetConfig;` to any bean

Call `/refresh` endpoint to refresh beans by new values from property sources

Please make a solution uniform with Spring ecosystem.

If you want to have dynamically to be dependent on, for example, `@PathVariable`:

```java
private Map<String, AppConfig> sourceToConfig;

@GetMapping("/{source}/foo")
public void baz(@PathVariable source) {
     AppConfig revelantConfig = sourceToConfig.get(source);
     ...
}
```

Spring provides the opportunity to automatically collect a map of beans where bean key is a bean name.

Rename bean methods above from `twilConfig` to `twil()` and call you endpoint like: `/twil/foo` (*twilConfig* is a bad path for an endpoint)

Comment: but how can decide this at runtime based on request param... when you do autowiring it will be at app atartup time right

Comment: It wasn't mentioned that you gonna be dependent on request param. It s better to use url path `@PathVariable`, I'll update the reply above